# Call method within render or use getter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getter, es6-class

When a render method should return a calculated value, is it more appropriate to use a class method

```
class User extends Component {
  getFullName () {
    const { fname, lname } = this.props
    return `${lname}, ${fname}`
  }
  render () {
    return <div>FULLNAME: {this.getFullName()}</div>
  }
}
```

or a getter:

```
class User extends Component {
  get fullName () {
    const { fname, lname } = this.props
    return `${lname}, ${fname}`
  }
  render () {
    return <div>FULLNAME: {this.fullName}</div>
  }
}
```

They both seem to work, but I'm unclear if calling a function within a render method is good practice or not and am curious if one is preferred over the other and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a render method should return a calculated value, is it more appropriate to use a class method?

There's really no right or wrong here.  It's just a matter of personal preference and coding style and what type of interface you prefer on your object.

If you want it to behave and seem to the caller like it's a property, then use a getter so the caller can access it like a property `console.log(user.fullName)`.

If you want it to behave and seem to the caller like something that the object has to compute and return, then use a method (console.log(user.getFullName())`.

In this particular case, either is just fine.  Since there's no setter, I'd personally probably use `user.getFullName()` myself so it's clear to the caller that this is something that can only be retrieved, not set and is probably a computed property, not something that is directly stored.

> They both seem to work, but I'm unclear if calling a function within a render method is good practice or not and am curious if one is preferred over the other and why.

There's no issue at all with calling a function inside of `render()`.  That's perfectly fine.

Comment: Excellent advice. Thanks much!